# concat in concat mysql

Tags: mysql, concatenation

lets say i have a table like this

```
+-----+---------------+
| id  |     name      |
+-----+---------------+
|   1 | Meatball 300g |
+-----+---------------+
```

how do i made the url column with this format > myurl.com/id product/name (but separate with "-")

so based on expected results, it's should be like this

```
+-----+---------------+---------------------------+
| id  |     name      |            url            |
+-----+---------------+---------------------------+
|   1 | Meatball 300g | myurl.com/1/Meatball-300g |
+-----+---------------+---------------------------+
```

i try with this but dont have any idea with the concat inside concat

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS("/","myurl.com",id,CONCAT(dont know if this format concat was right)) AS url
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use single quotes for string literals, and I think you want:

```sql
SELECT id, name, CONCAT_WS('/', 'myurl.com', id, REPLACE(name, ' ', '-')) AS url
FROM yourTable;
```